# mod rewrite root url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been developing a site on a temporary url:

```
 http://00.00.00.00/~myurl
```

now Ive put the site live on www.myurl.org.uk - problem is all the links on the pages don't resolve the temporary url 
is there a way to put something in the htaccess to rewrite '00.00.00.00/~myurl' as 'www.myurl.org.uk' wherever it sees occurs to save me trawling the whole site - or is this bad practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite rules occur after the http request, which is going to the wrong (non-existant) address.  So no you can't fix this with a RewriteRule .

Also, in the future you may want to use relative links and/or a `<base href="">` tag.

Edit:

I may have misunderstood your question.  If http://00.00.00.00 is just the ip address of http://www.myurl.org.uk , and you want people to show the hostname rather than the ip address in their url bar, you could do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.myurl.org.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.myurl.org.uk/$1 [QSA,L,R]
```

Although redirecting every link click is an ugly hack, I would just fix it properly in the code.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately the site is wordpress and the realtive links aren't generated automatically when linking within posts... never mind, I'll do it the old fashioned way!!

Comment: actually isnt there a way to do a blanket redirect, so anything with '00.00.00.00/~myurl/whatever' redirects to 'www.myurl.org.uk/whatever'?

Comment: sorry forgot to put your name on the above two comments

Comment: What is http://00.00.00.00 ?  I assume you're just using this as a placeholder for a real ip address, but where does it go?  Is http://00.00.00.00 the ip address for http://www.myurl.org.uk , or does it go somewhere else, like a local or development server?

Comment: When developing the site i did it on a temporary url ` http://00.00.00.00/~myurl` - as I said in my OP. When the nameservers were redirect this became my live site - www.myurl.org.uk. Wordpress made all the links automatically (no relatively) as ` http://00.00.00.00/~myurl/mypage` - I thought I was pretty clear actually! These things are so hard to translate online!